# How to add user input at caret position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am facing a weird issue regarding a textbox after using validation for preventing special characters.Lets say I enter some text in it.Now if I change the caret position in between the already entered text and try to add text there, the caret automatically jumps to the end of the text.

Any workaround for this?

Note:- I am using IE 11.

Textbox :-

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label data-i18n="rpt_name"></label>
          <span class="required">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subNameID">
 </div>
```

The source of error is validation for avoiding special characters.

```
 $('#subNameID').bind('keypress', function (e) {

        if ($('#subNameID').val().length == 0) {
            var k = e.which;
            var ok = k >= 65 && k <= 90 || // A-Z
                k >= 97 && k <= 122 || // a-z
                k >= 48 && k <= 57; // 0-9

            if (!ok) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    })
```

Also tried using below solution but gives the same issue.

```
$("#subNameID").on("keypress keyup paste", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 8)
        return true;
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\s]/g, '');
});
```

Comment: Please show us some code in order to debug the error.

Comment: Search for the posts of the user Tim Down, he has some great answers to question like these.

Comment: what's your requirement here ? what characters you need to prevent ?

Comment: I want to allow a-z ,A-Z , 0-9, space,backspace,delete,enter.Apart from these I want to restrict any special character like <_-> !@#$%^&*(),.